# DEVISE RAILS 3 Problem

Tags: routes, devise, ruby-on-rails-3

edit:
i tried different devise versions: 1.2.1, 1.2.rc2 and 1.1.8...

i use in development:
-ruby 1.9.p0
-rails 3.0.1

my routes are:

```
...
devise_for :users
resources :users
...
namespace :admin do
    devise_for :admins, :module => "devise", :controllers => { :sessions => "admin/sessions" } do
      get "login", :to => "admin/sessions#new"
      get "logout", :to => "admin/sessions#destroy"
    end
    resources :admins
end
...
```

on production enviroment i use ruby 1.9.2p180 and devise is routes are broken... Only admin routes gets generated, user-routing is out of contact... Can someone help me please?
server is passenger with apache2.

Comment: How are they broken? Does rake:routes show no user routes at all?  When I use devise, I just use devise_for for both users and admins, and have no problems...it looks like you're trying to use custom controllers for admins, though?  Are you just using default controllers for users, then? Maybe your default controllers have problems, somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can not declare users two times you should remove **resources :users**
you can declare users in namespace.